# How to cut video, add audio and burn subtitle while cropping video all in one command - ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, command-line, ffprobe, ffplay

Currently I have the following command,

which cuts the video, adds audio and burns subtitle into the video.

```
-ss 00:00:30 -t -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -vcodec copy  -acodec copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -vf subtitles=subtitle.srt
```

but I need to crop the video before the subtitle is added. I know it is possible to crop video using the command:

```
-vf crop=405:720
```

or using

```
-filter:v crop=405:720
```

but I am unable to use it in conjunction with the above statement. What would be the best approch to get the desribed outcome?

Comment: crop uses 4 variables crop=405:720:0:0 where 0:0 is the x,y coordinates of the 405:720 crop
also ... I doubt it you can codec copy, because there is a change in size of the frames, therefore you need to reencode

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer:

```
ffmpeg.exe -ss 00:00:30 -t 00:00:10 -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:a copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0  -vf "crop=405:720,subtitles=subtitle.srt"  output.mp4
```